# get <NA> when using as.factor()

Tags: r, boxplot, na, factors

I am trying to convert every value of a data.frame column into factors, this is so I can use them as the "groups" in a boxplot graph. However, using both the as.factor() and factor() function, it turns every value into . There are 5 different cell types in the column, CD8, CD4, Bcell, Mono, Gran - and all turn to NA.

Confusingly, when i apply the function to just one row of the column then it works perfectly fine. The dataframe is very very large (over 3 million rows) - could this be the cause of the issue?

Code :

```
> head(BP)
 Methylation Cell_Type
  1  0.03219298       CD8
  2  0.11684228       CD8
  3  0.04214158       CD8
  4  0.26700497       CD8
  5  0.34251732       CD8
  6  0.34231208       CD8

> BP$Cell_Type <- as.factor(BP$Cell_Type)

  > head(BP)
     Methylation Cell_Type
   1  0.03219298      <NA>
   2  0.11684228      <NA>
   3  0.04214158      <NA>
   4  0.26700497      <NA>
   5  0.34251732      <NA>
   6  0.34231208      <NA>
```

Unsure why this is happening - any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Out put of dput(head(BP))

```
> dput(head(BP))
 structure(list(Methylation = c(0.0321929818018839, 
 0.116842281589967, 
 0.0421415803696093, 0.267004971824527, 0.342517319094108, 
 0.342312083101948
 ), Cell_Type = structure(list(Cell_Type = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Bcell", "CD4", "CD8", "Gran", "Mono"
 ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = 
 "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add the results of `dput(head(BP))` to your question please

Comment: thanks for the update charlie. If you look at your data (use `str(BP)` ) you will see that it has nested dataframes i.e. `Cell_Type` is a dataframe. To get your code to work you should first convert this to a vector. So use `BP$Cell_Type <- as.factor(unlist(BP$Cell_Type))` but really you should find why you have this format in your code and sort it.

Comment: ... when you do `str(BP)` you will notice that the column is already a `factor` in the nested dataframe. So it is enough to do `BP$Cell_Type <- unlist(BP$Cell_Type)`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe make sure `Cell_Type` is a character first?

```
BP <- tibble::tribble(
     ~Methylation, ~Cell_Type,
  0.03219298,  "CD8",
  0.11684228,  "CD8",
  0.04214158,  "CD8",
  0.26700497,  "CD8",
  0.34251732,  "CD8",
  0.34231208,  "CD8")

BP$Cell_Type <- as.factor(BP$Cell_Type)  


print(BP)

Methylation Cell_Type
        <dbl> <fct>    
1      0.0322 CD8      
2      0.117  CD8      
3      0.0421 CD8      
4      0.267  CD8      
5      0.343  CD8      
6      0.342  CD8
```

Or simply

```
BP$Cell_Type <- as.factor(as.character(BP$Cell_Type))
```

Comment: in theory this should work, but there might be something odd in the OP's data.frame, or the column is some other class.